# Yet another list csv file in Python question

Tags: python, csv

I have a file csv file in this format, I would like to generate the average for each step:

```
elapsed,label
120,Step 01
260,Step 02
113,Step 03
100,Step 01
200,Step 02
103,Step 03
```

but am having a hard time figuring the lists out. The Python script that I am using is:

```
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
  for row in csv.DictReader(open(file)):
    label = row['label']
    elapsed = row['elapsed']
    print elapsed,label
```

I've tried

`label.append(row['elapsed'])` and `label.append('elapsed')`, but in each case I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I am unsure how to get past this error. I'm new to Python, so perhaps I am missing something in the way lists work? If I can get a list like [120,100] for step 01, I can easily sum and average it, but it is the list creation part that I am stuck on.

**Edit: Sum of `result` list**

Now, I have this:

```
  for item in result:
    for n in result[item]:
      int(n)
      print sum(float(result[item][n]))
```

but get this error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

But "n" is an integer already, no ... ? Or is this referring to "item"? I think I am more confused now than before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to make lists,

```
from collections import defaultdict
steps = defaultdict(list)

for file in sys.argv[1:]:
  for row in csv.DictReader(open(file)):
    steps[row['label']].append(row['elapsed'])

averages = dict((key, sum(value)) for key, value in steps.iteritems())
```

Will give you the averages.

What you're doing is attempting to add the string in `row['elapsed']` to the string in `label`, but strings are immutable so can't be appended to. You can join them with `string1 + string2` or `''.join((string1, string2)).

EDIT: Also, for your new error, See the last line of my code, or, try:

```
averages = {}
for item in result.iteritems():
    print item[0], sum(item[1])
```

Comment: Not really a solution for what he wants to achieve. You should have noticed that his approach is totally wrong.

Comment: Thanks @agf, I get this error when running this script: `TypeError: first argument must be callable`. I then removed `[]` from `defaultdict([])`, and then get this: `KeyError:'Step 01'`

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should achieve what you're attempting:

```
result = dict()
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
  for row in csv.DictReader(open(file)):
    label = row['label']
    elapsed = float(row['elapsed'])
    if label in result:
      result[label].append(elapsed)
    else:
      result[label] = [elapsed]

totals = dict((label, sum(values)) for label, values in result.iteritems())
```

After executing this, `result` will contain the lists in the format you wanted.

Comment: Additionally, you can get the step number as an integer by `int(label[5:])`.

Comment: You want a `defaultdict` here, as I used in my answer.

Comment: @agf thanks! I'm still learning Python myself and I didn't know about it.

Comment: Thanks @Pablo. I just updated my question, as now I am seeing another error ... perhaps I underestimated this exercise ... what am I missing ... ?

Comment: @ms4py, I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by `int(label[5:])` ... could you perhaps put that in context ... ?

Comment: @KM He meant that you can extract the '02' part from 'Step 02' by using label[5:]. The error you're getting now is because elapsed is still a string. Change `elapsed = row['elapsed']` into `elapsed = float(row['elapsed'])`. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

Many thanks to @Pablo, @agf & @ms4py. Your input brought me to this.

```
result = dict()
av = []
idx = []
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
  for row in csv.DictReader(open(file)):
    label = row['label']
    elapsed = row['elapsed']
    if label in result:
      result[label].append(elapsed)
    else:
      result[label] = [elapsed]    
  for i in sorted (result.iterkeys()):
    s = sum(int(v) for v in result[i])
    a = s/float(len(result[i]))
```